# iOS 9 Safe Area Top constraint of xib and storyboard is different

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout, safearealayoutguide

on iOS 9, iPhone 5, not happend on iOS 10 and later

UIViewController create from storyboard, I set the viewController's red subView's view.top equals to safe area top, the red view is just below the statusBar.

If create viewController from xib file, use `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)` and also set red subView's view.top equals to safe area top, the red view is at same origin.y with the statusBar. Just as below:

The viewControllers create from storyboard and xib are the same class, maybe create from storyboard and xib have some different setting, I try to unselect all storyboard select option, but have not found the one that make the difference.

Can any one explain this? Thanks!

Repo for this question: https://github.com/codingingBoy/SafeAreaDemo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are backward compatibility issues with XIBs and Safe-Area guides with older iOS versions, because the XIB files did not have them.

> In the current Xib backwards deployment behavior (iOS 10 and prior), a constraint to the safe area will be converted to the superview, because a XIB does not have top and bottom layout guides.
>
> This may not achieve the layout behavior that you want, and we recommend you working around this case with one of the following options:
>
> 1) move the the view and layout to a storyboard view controller
>
> 2) use IB Outlets to the relevant (top and bottom) constraints, and programatically replace them with constraints to top/bottom layout guide once the view gets installed
>
> 3) install the view as a subview, and programmatically add constraints to top/bottom layout guides and sides.

Ref: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87329

Comment: Thank you for you explanation and solution!